# Why is my dev front controller included in Assetic URLs?

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm using Assetic to include Javascript files, but when used in the dev environment, `/app_dev.php` is added to the beginning of the URL, so the final url looks like `/app_dev.php/js/something.js`. This results in a 404 when trying to load the JS. When I access the site from the production environment the URLs *don't* include `/app_dev.php` and everything works fine.

I could add a conditional that checks if it's the dev environment and call `str_replace` on the URLs, but I'd like to solve the root of this problem, if possible.

**Edit**

@gilden, I would understand that in dev they would get processed every time, but the URLs simply result in 404s.

Here's my Assetic config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        # yui_css:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar
```

And here's how I'm using it in my template (app/Resources/views/base.html.php)

```
foreach ($view['assetic']->javascripts(
            array('@AssetsBundle/Resources/public/js/*'), array(), array('output' => 'js/combined.js')) as $url) {
            echo 'url: ' . $url . '<br />';    
        }
```

I then include $url using a custom helper I wrote, but it already contains app_dev.php at that point.

Comment: This is the intended behavior - in the dev environment your scripts get processed every time by Assetic to simplify development. I'm guessing Assetic is not properly configured. Could you post the part of your config regarding Assetic? It would also be nice to see your template as well.

Comment: Ah! I didn't even think of looking in config_dev.yml. That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used php templating in Symfony so I'm afraid I don't have the best answer. By using some custom code, you're probably circumventing some internal logic, which handles the request to a controller.

As a workaround you could try removing `assetic: use_controller: true` from `/app/config_dev.yml`.